# lossy conversion from int to byte?

Tags: java, encryption

my simple encryption algorithim i am doing as an exercise is giving me a possible lossy conversion from int to byte? but i dont know why it is giving me this error any ideas?

```
public class Rot13Crypt extends CryptStream
{
    public Rot13Crypt(StreamPair theStreams)
    {
        super(theStreams);
    }
    protected byte [] cryptData(byte [] data, int len)
    {
        byte [] cryptedByte = new byte[len];
        for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        {
            cryptedByte[i] = (data[i] + 13) % 256;
        }
        return cryptedByte;
    }
    protected byte [] decryptData(byte [] data, int len)
    {
        byte [] decryptedByte = new byte[len];
        for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        {
            decryptedByte[i] = (data[i] * 256) - 13;
        }
        return decryptedByte;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide the complete compilation error message / messages including the line numbers.

Answer (score 5):

It is giving that error message because you are attempting to assign the value of an int-valued expression to a `byte`.  That is a potentially lossy operation: intuitively, you cannot put all possible `int` values into a `byte`.

The Java language requires you to use a `(byte)` cast when you assign an int-valued expression to a `byte`.

There are two places where you are doing this:

```
   cryptedByte[i] = (data[i] + 13) % 256;

   decryptedByte[i] = (data[i] * 256) - 13;
```

In the first one, the value of the expression is in the range 0 to 255 ... but Java `byte` values are in the range -128 to +127.

In the second one, the expression values potentially have values in the range `(-128 * 256) - 13` to `(+127 * 256) - 13.  That clearly won't fit.

But that is actually moot.  The Java does not allow variants of the above code even if you (a smart human being) can **prove** that the range of the expression would "fit" into a `byte`.  The JLS forbids this.  (A Java compiler not required to be a general theorem prover!!)

The *only* situation where an int-valued expression can be assigned to a `byte` without a type-cast is when the expression is a compile-time constant expression *AND* the actual value of the expression is in the range of `byte`.

If you are interested, this is specified in [JLS 15.2 Assignment Contexts](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2) which states:

> In addition, if the expression is a constant expression (§15.28) of type byte, short, char, or int:
>
> - A narrowing primitive conversion may be used if the type of the variable is byte, short, or char, and the value of the constant expression is representable in the type of the variable.

(You need to chase down what the spec means by "constant expression" and "narrowing primitive conversion".  I'll leave that for interested people to do for themselves.)

---

> so would i add a (byte) cast in front of the 13 and 256?

Nope.  You need to cast the entire expression; e.g.

```
   cryptedByte[i] = (byte) ((data[i] + 13) % 256);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I couldn't figure it out at first but now i get it

Answer (score 3):

In Java, the `int` type is coded using 32 bits and the `byte` type using 8 bits. If you convert an `int` to a `byte`, you may lose information if your original value is greater than 127 or less than -128.

An integer literal is by default an `int` and operations on `int` return `int`. So the result of `data[i] + 13` is an `int`; the same for `(data[i] + 13) % 256`. When you try to store that result into a `byte` (here cryptedByte[i]), Java warns you about the "possible lossy conversion".

Comment: so would i add a (byte) cast in front of the 13 and 256?

Comment: No just cast the whole result to byte: cryptedByte[i] = (byte) ((data[i] + 13) % 256);

Answer (score 1):

A byte has 2^8 = 256 unique states and so the largest range it can represent is -128 to 127.

so assuming that in

```
 decryptedByte[i] = (data[i] * 256) - 13;
```

the `data[i]` value is greater than `1` will cause the value to overflow the max value of a byte

Comment: `byte` in Java is signed - it can contain numbers between -128 and 127, not 255.

Answer (score 0):

You have problems here

```
cryptedByte[i] = (data[i] + 13) % 256;
```

and here

```
decryptedByte[i] = (data[i] * 256) - 13;
```

`256` and `13` are literals of type `int`. When you perform operations with them and with a type that occupies less memory (in this example, `byte`), *type promotion* occurs: `data[i]` is *implicitly* converted (promoted) to type `int`. Thus, both these expressions evaluate to `int`. And you know what happens when you convert an int to a byte, right? You can *lose* data. That is because a `byte` is limited to less memory than `int`.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to do a cast when assigning each byte when it's inside a variable, so java can assure all are between -127 and 127 which is the ascii range. The folowing should work:

```
public class Rot13Crypt extends CryptStream
{
    public Rot13Crypt(StreamPair theStreams)
    {
        super(theStreams);
    }
    protected byte [] cryptData(byte [] data, int len)
    {
        byte [] cryptedByte = new byte[len];
        for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        {
            cryptedByte[i] = (byte) (data[i] + 13) % 256;
        }
        return cryptedByte;
    }
    protected byte [] decryptData(byte [] data, int len)
    {
        byte [] decryptedByte = new byte[len];
        for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        {
            decryptedByte[i] = (byte) (data[i] * 256) - 13;
        }
        return decryptedByte;
    }
```

}

Answer (score -1):

Bytes have a size of 8 bits and ints a size of 32 bits. So some information may be lost by doing this conversion!

Answer (score -1):

byte data type is an 8-bit signed two's complement integer.
int data type is a 32-bit signed two's complement integer.

Can't fit an integer into a byte. Hence, the loss in precision.
I hope it's clear.

A sample reference is [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_basic_datatypes.htm)