# Why this programme shows a compile error?

Tags: java

```
class Example{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        byte b1=10,b2=20,b3;    
        b3=b1+b2;
        System.out.println(b3);
    }   
}
```

Comment: If only compile errors included some kind of information about what the problem was.

Comment: The java compiler usually aids you why it is unable to compile. Try to read the message(s) it is displaying so that you can figure out the problem quickly. That is a good skill for in the future when facing compilation problems of a big project.

Comment: It showed this. possible lossy conversion from int to byte

Comment: Here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28623477/lossy-conversion-from-int-to-byte

Answer (score 1):

Adding two bytes produces an `int`. You cannot assign an `int` to a `byte` without casting it.

You need to do this:

```
byte b1 = 10, b2 = 20, b3;
b3 = (byte) (b1 + b2);
System.out.println(b3);
```

Or this:

```
byte b1 = 10, b2 = 20;
int b3 = b1 + b2;
System.out.println(b3);
```